# Tween does NOT repeat indefinitely

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, flash-cs5

I am trying to animate a hexagon spinning like a wheel indefinitely:

```
function rotateCW(e:TweenEvent = null):void{
    var hexRot:Tween = new Tween(this, "rotationZ", None.easeNone, 0, 360, 2, true);
    hexRot.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, rotateCW);        
}
```

For some strange reason the animation stops after a random amount of repetitions. It varies anything from between 2 and 600 times before it stops.

I've got a whole bunch of different events firing all over the place in my application, is it possible that this might cause the MOTION_FINISH event to either not fire or not get caught?

Thanks!

Comment: i recommend to use external tween classes for that check this www.greensock.com, you will get better methods, performance and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should define `hexRot` and listen to its MOTION_FINISH outisde of your function. By doing like you do, every hexRot stays in memory since it has a listener attached to it.

This may not solve your problem but it will be a cleaner way to write things and you will be less vulnerable to strange behaviors.

```
private var hexRot:Tween;

/**
*Run only once
*/
function init():void {
    hexRot = new Tween(this, "rotationZ", None.easeNone, 0, 360, 2, true);
    hexRot.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, rotateCW); 
}

function rotateCW(e:TweenEvent = null):void{    
    hexRot.start();       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment about every hexRot that stays in memory makes sense. I presume the problem is I run out of memory, or out of available event listener, and then the garbage collector cleans up?

I separated the code and put the tween and event declaration in a constructor, and simply called the start() outside. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The flash Garbage collector has cleaned up your hexRot-variable, so the animation stopped. To fix this, use the solution Kodiak has provided :) When the variable is globally declared, it won't get collected as long as you don't put anything new in the variable.